# Text classification CNN overfits training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a CNN architecture to classify text sentences. The architecture of the network is as follows:

```
text_input = Input(shape=X_train_vec.shape[1:], name = "Text_input")

conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(text_input)
drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop21)
conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(pool1)
drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)
pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop22)
dense = Dense(16, activation='relu')(pool2)

flat = Flatten()(dense)
dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
out = Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense)

outputs = Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=outputs)
# compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I have some callbacks as early_stopping and reduceLR to stop the training and to reduce the learning rate when the validation loss is not improving (reducing).

```
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                               patience=5)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
                                   save_weights_only=False,
                                   monitor='val_loss',
                                   mode="auto",
                                   save_best_only=True)
learning_rate_decay = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                                        factor=0.1, 
                                        patience=2, 
                                        verbose=1, 
                                        mode='auto',
                                        min_delta=0.0001, 
                                        cooldown=0,
                                        min_lr=0)
```

Once the model is trained the history of the training goes as follows:
[image]

We can observe here that the validation loss is not improving from epoch 5 on and that the training loss is being overfitted with each step.

I will like to know if I'm doing something wrong in the architecture of the CNN? Aren't enough the dropout layers to avoid the overfitting? Which are other ways to reduce overfitting?

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

I have tried also with regularization an the result where even worse:

```
kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)
```

[image]

---

Edit 2:

I have tried to apply BatchNormalization layers after each convolution and the result is the next one:

```
norm = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
```

[image]

---

Edit 3:

After applying the LSTM architecture:

```
text_input = Input(shape=X_train_vec.shape[1:], name = "Text_input")

conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(text_input)
drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(drop21)
drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)

lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences = True))(drop22)
lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True))(lstm1)

flat = Flatten()(lstm2)
dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
out = Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense)

outputs = Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=outputs)
# compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image]

Comment: The most important question is: "How large is your dataset?" This seems like a very small dataset. If that is the case, your primary reaction should be to gather more data.

Comment: It is not small. I have like 40000 samples.

Comment: Then there must be some other problem. Since the validation loss is barely decreasing it´s not learning anything useful. How many classes do you have? Are your classes balanced?

Comment: There are two classes and the distribution is 58%, 42%

Comment: Hmm. It´s hard to guess without further information, but I still suppose that there might be something wrong with the data. Is this a custom project? What are you trying to predict?

Comment: Yes it is a custom project. I am trying to predict the category of an incident based on the input text of the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216056/discussion-between-felix-kleine-bosing-and-imb).

Comment: Has adding Conv Layer helped you?

Comment: Can you please specify X_train_vec.shape[1:] and y_train.shape[1]?

Comment: X_train_vec[1:] is of (1000,1) and y_train[1] is of 2

Comment: How do the images look like? Is it one image containing multiple text rows or one row per image? Maybe line segmentation would help. And then indeed including recurrent layers to preserve structural information from the past while iterating through the remainder of the image

Comment: It seems that training and validation datasets are completely different in nature. We get these types of charts when we try transfer learning with only one or at max two layers as trainable. So I would suggest to shuffle the data and then split train and validation data.

Comment: There are no images @DanielB. the dataset is made of text and the aim is classification.

Comment: The test and train datasets are taken from the same data @jarryjafery, I have also tried to validate the training of the NN splitting the training set and the results were the same.

Comment: But for what reason did you choose to employ a CNN? Since it is text sequences, I would expect RNNs to perform better on the task. And besides that: how is the text in the dataset represented? Sparse or dense word embeddings?

Comment: @DanielB. It was used in other experiment with the same purpose of text classification. Even so, I have also used RNN using LSTM cells and the output was the same.

Answer (score 2):

overfitting can caused by many factors, it happens when your model fits too well to the training set.

To handle it you can do some ways:

> 1. Add more data
> 2. Use data augmentation
> 3. Use architectures that generalize well
> 4. Add regularization (mostly dropout, L1/L2 regularization are also possible)
> 5. Reduce architecture complexity.

for more clearly you can read in https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-3-more-on-cnns-handling-overfitting-2bd5d99abe5d

Answer (score 1):

This is screaming **Transfer Learning**. `google-unversal-sentence-encoder` is perfect for this use case. Replace your model with

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub 
import tensorflow_text

text_input = Input(shape=X_train_vec.shape[1:], name = "Text_input")

# this next layer might need some tweaking dimension wise, to correctly fit
# X_train in the model
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.squeeze(x))(text_input)
# conv2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(text_input)
# drop21 = Dropout(0.5)(conv2)
# pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop21)
# conv22 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(pool1)
# drop22 = Dropout(0.5)(conv22)
# pool2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(drop22)

# 1) you might need `text_input = tf.expand_dims(text_input, axis=0)` here
# 2) If you're classifying English only, you can use the link to the normal `google-universal-sentence-encoder`, not the multilingual one
# 3) both the English and multilingual have a `-large` version. More accurate but slower to train and infer. 
embedded = hub.KerasLayer('https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/3')(text_input) 

# this layer seems out of place, 
# dense = Dense(16, activation='relu')(embedded) 

# you don't need to flatten after a dense layer (in your case) or a backbone (in my case (google-universal-sentence-encoder))
# flat = Flatten()(dense)

dense = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat)
out = Dense(32, activation='relu')(dense)

outputs = Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='softmax')(out)

model = Model(inputs=text_input, outputs=outputs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try and I'll tell you.

Comment: did this not work for you? If not, I will remove the answer again.

Comment: I have problems to execute it: ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [?,1], [].

Comment: did you try  `text_input = tf.expand_dims(text_input, axis=0)` or `text_input = tf.squeeze(text_input)` right before the `tf.KerasLayer`?

Comment: both of them end in this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'

Comment: ah yes you need to wrap it in a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` layer, I updated my answer

Comment: Now we have the same error as before with one more dimension:     ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 3 for 'text_preprocessor/tokenize/StringSplit/StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [1,?,1], [].

Comment: Almost there - I think now it's `squeeze ` instead of `expand_dims`. I updated my answer again.

Comment: With squeeze we are with the same error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'

Comment: do you have some sample data for `X_train_vec`?

Comment: Finally I have embedded first the train and test sets and then start the network. The results were as the previous experiments, the network wasn't learning and I  tried different network architectures with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are doing a text Classification, adding 1 or 2 LSTM layers might help the network learn better, since it will be able to better associate with the context of the data. I suggest adding the following code before the flatten layer.

```
lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequence = True))
lstm2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(64))
```

LSTM layers can help neural network learn association between certain words and might improve the accuracy of your network.

I also Suggest dropping the Max Pooling layers as max pooling especially in text classification can lead the network to drop some of the useful features.
Just keep the convolutional Layers and the dropout. Also remove the Dense layer before flatten and add the aforementioned LSTMs.

Comment: I've tried the architecture you presented but the results where worst than only with convolutions. The validation loss didn't start decreasing until 12nd epoch and once it started to go down it only improved 1 percent from 0.5754 to 0.5913. Moreover val_loss was always higher that train loss (accuracy also was higher). I guess this is a weird situation, I'm attaching the figure as edit in the question.

Comment: Try adding a  Embedding Layer.

Comment: I tried adding a fasttext embedding layer. And the results were also bad.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how you feed the text into your model. I am assuming that you tokenize the text to represent it as a sequence of integers, but do you use any word embedding prior to feeding it into your model? If not, I suggest you to throw atrainable tensorflow [`Embedding`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding) layer at the start of your model. There is a clever technique called Embedding Lookup to speed up its training, but you can save it for later. Try adding this layer to your model. Then your `Conv1D` layer would have a much easier time working on a sequence of floats. Also, I suggest you throw [`BatchNormalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization) after each `Conv1D`, it should help to speed up convergence and training.

Comment: I have added a fasttext embedding layer and batch normalization but the results were as the rest.